# TypeError: func.toString is not a function

Tags: node.js, fastify

I was building a website with Fastify, and recently updated it to the latest version. After that, I converted my code from CommonJS to ES6. Once I did that, I suddenly ran into an error that I did not encounter before.

```
TypeError: func.toString is not a function
    at Object.getFuncPreview (/home/aditya/Development/launchbase/node_modules/.pnpm/fastify@4.7.0/node_modules/fastify/lib/pluginUtils.js:44:15)
    at Boot.override (/home/aditya/Development/launchbase/node_modules/.pnpm/fastify@4.7.0/node_modules/fastify/lib/pluginOverride.js:52:78)
    at Plugin.exec (/home/aditya/Development/launchbase/node_modules/.pnpm/avvio@8.2.0/node_modules/avvio/plugin.js:79:33)
    at Boot.loadPlugin (/home/aditya/Development/launchbase/node_modules/.pnpm/avvio@8.2.0/node_modules/avvio/plugin.js:272:10)
    at /home/aditya/Development/launchbase/node_modules/.pnpm/avvio@8.2.0/node_modules/avvio/plugin.js:262:18
```

I am not able to find the exact source of the issue, for the error message. However, I found all the instances of using `toString' in my code.

```js
const { randomBytes, scryptSync } = await import('crypto');
const salt = randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
const hashedStr = scryptSync(str, salt, 64).toString('hex');
```

Can someone help me debug this issue?

Comment: I think you may have a plugin that is not a plugin. While you have updated to the latest version, did you read the breaking changes?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon Can you elaborate? I checked the breaking changes. I don't think I have an issue there.

Comment: Could you isolate the issue by sharing an example of your ESM conversion?

Comment: its issue with your "plugin" as pointed by Manuel not crypto module.

Answer (score 0):

You should import the functions with:

```
const { randomBytes, scryptSync } = require('crypto');
```